# Giving a 3D object a CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, r, 3d

I am not sure if this question makes sense; I have a 3D model segment of land. Because it is a 3D model, it does not have a CRS(??). I process it in CloudCompare and eventually export a raster of some parameter. I then import it into QGIS along with a pre-made shapefile of the same area (CRS: WGS84). However, the two do not match up because the raster does not have the same CRS or extent. I have tried using R to project the raster to the shapefiles CRS, but I don't have a starting CRS, so R wouldn't know how to convert it. So how does one put a CRS into a 3D model, preferably in R.

Files that I am using (scene_mesh_decimated_textured)
[image]

I was given another file (image 2) that already had a CRS attached to it (WGS84). I did my processes and when imported the raster into QGIS, it worked. I don't understand how the 3D model could have a CRS with it? Is it because it is a .las file type?

[image]

Comment: What sort of file is your 3d model stored in? If you export a raster with no coordinate system then you have to "georeference" it somehow, perhaps by identifying its corner coordinates in lat-long which places it on the globe.

Comment: See edits above. I was thinking about just georeferencing it as well.